# How can I connect several USB 2.0 webcams to a single host?

Tags: usb, webcam, usb-3

I am trying to run several (up to 6) USB 2.0 webcams off of a single computer which has one USB 3.0 host and one USB 2.0 host. With each of the cameras streaming at about 15 MB/s (1080p30 MJPEG), I thought that I would be able to run them all through the USB 3.0 host by using the corresponding ports, and that the host would automatically negotiate the translation from 2.0 to 3.0. However, per [this previous answer](https://superuser.com/a/624312/1091519), it seems that all traffic from USB 2.0 devices is sent through the USB 2.0 host--enforcing the USB 2.0 bandwidth limit and making it impossible to run even 2 cameras concurrently!

Is it possible to find some kind of adapter to convert USB 2.0 signals to USB 3.0 (I've had no luck searching Amazon and Newegg)? Or would I need to install a separate PCIe USB expansion card for *each* camera to run them all at the same time?

Comment: How did you come up with the 15 MB/sec number?

Comment: @SamForbis I ran usbtop to check the host usage

Comment: May be you should change you focus on web cams with real USB 3.0 support.

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert USB2 into USB3.

One way solve your problem is to get a newer computer with USB 3.1 compliant xHCI controllers. AFAIK these controllers don't have single USB2 bandwidth limitation, each root port has full USB2 bandwidth. The results however are mixed, see [some details here](https://superuser.com/a/1234391/620011).

And having a bunch of PCIe extra cards will do the job as well. There also are single-board PCIe cards with multiple individual host controllers.